# How to get country code according to current location?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-location

I have code for getting country codes. But i want country code like  +91 for india. how to get that ?

```
NSArray *countryCodes = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];     
NSMutableArray *countries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[countryCodes count]];
for (NSString *countryCode in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes])  {    
    NSString *identifier = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: countryCode forKey: NSLocaleCountryCode]];
    NSString *country = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey: NSLocaleIdentifier value: identifier];
    [countries addObject: country];
}

NSDictionary *codeForCountryDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:countryCodes forKeys:countries];

NSLog(@”%@”,codeForCountryDictionary);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CoreTelephony framework for this purpose. Include this framework in your project

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *network_Info = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
CTCarrier *carrier = network_Info.subscriberCellularProvider;
NSString *countryCode = carrier.mobileCountryCode
```